# Итераторы, генераторы

Tags: php, javascript, итераторы

Зачем на практике нужны итераторы? Вообще, интересует в общем-то php и js, но они же есть во многих языках.
Например зачем мне библиотека SPL и её интерфейсы итераторов, если у меня есть итерируемый массив, по которому можно пробежаться форычом. 
Хотелось бы увидеть примеры использования итераторов тогда, когда по другому проблему решить нельзя.
Опять же я могу представить себе какую-либо структуру кастомную, по которой требуется чтобы можно было бегать как по массиву, тогда пишем итератор для неё. Но вот примеры костыльных собственных структур в php я не припомню. 
Ни разу не сталкивался с какими нибудь стеками, очередями и другими структурами в wordpress, joomla, drupal, сайты на yii2, symfony и т.д.

Тот же вопрос к генератором - их практическое использование. Ну тут допустим пригодятся они для обработки логов сервера. Нам нужна статистика, сколько хостов и т.д. и открыть файл лога мы не можем, он большой, а так скачиваем по строку и запросами в бд обновляем статистику и так пока не обработаем файл. Я правильно понимаю? Но опять же логично что такой софт будет писаться на c++, python или другом языке, но никак не на php.

Answer (score 2):

Так `foreach` как раз с итератором и работает. Оно и есть самый простой пример.

Фактически, напрямую, без использования итератора, можно перебрать только индексированный массив. Если вы захотите перебрать ассоциативный массив без использования итератора, вам придется либо превратить его в индексированный, либо вытащить в индексированный массив его ключи и перебирать его с помощью `for`.

Вообще, итератор хорош тем, что уменьшает связность кода. Вам не нужно знать, сколько элементов в коллекции, какой следующий и т.д., вы просто говорите "дай еще один" и вам возвращается следующий либо `false`, если их больше нет.

Про генераторы, вот например одно из преимуществ [Потребление памяти PHP-генераторами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632826/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-php-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/632831#632831)